# Powershell mystical error

Tags: powershell

Please help! i'm confused what to do.
Script split files by content:

```
$InPC = "C:\Scripts\"

Get-ChildItem $InPC -Filter *.prt | ForEach-Object -Process { 
        $basename= $_.BaseName   
        $m = ( ( Get-Content $_ | Where { $_ | Select-String "---------------------  Instance Type and Transmission --------------" -Quiet } | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object { $_.Count } ) -ge 2) 
        $a=1
        if ($m) {
  Get-Content $_ | % {

    If ($_ -match "---------------------  Instance Type and Transmission --------------") {
        $OutputFile = "$basename-$a.prt"
        $a++
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $_
    }
  Remove-Item $_ 
  }
  }
```

Everything is going OK when i'm set-location to C:\Scripts. But in base case it won't work and give next error:

```
Get-Content : Path not found "C:\Users\a.ulianov\PRTPRT.prt".
C:\Scripts\2.ps1:23 знак:18
+         $m = ( ( Get-Content $_ | Where { $_ | Select-String "------------------ ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\a.ulianov\PRTPRT.prt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content : Path not found "C:\Users\a.ulianov\test.prt".
C:\Scripts\2.ps1:23 знак:18
+         $m = ( ( Get-Content $_ | Where { $_ | Select-String "------------------ ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\a.ulianov\test.prt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

it's seems to work with default PS location during excuting. What i might modify in this case?

#

thanks to @Raf @Rynant here is little crooked but working solution:

```
$InPC = "C:\Scripts"
Get-ChildItem -Path $InPC -Filter *.prt | ForEach-Object -Process { 
        $basename= $_.BaseName   
        $m = ( ( Get-Content $_.FullName | Where { $_ | Select-String "---------------------  Instance Type and Transmission --------------" -Quiet } | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object { $_.Count } ) -ge 2) 
        $a = 1
        if ($m) {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | % {

    If ($_ -match "---------------------  Instance Type and Transmission --------------") {
        $OutputFile = "$InPC\$basename _$a.prt"
        $a++
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $_
    }
  Remove-Item $_.FullName 
  }
  }
```

Comment: This isn't really an issue, but `$basename= % {$_.BaseName}` should just be `$basename = $_.BaseName`

Comment: thanks, i corrected the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a bit messy but I think the only change you need to do is replace:

```powershell
Get-Content $_
```

with

```powershell
Get-Content $_.FullName
```

Comment: this is didn't do the trick ((( at this time result is that newer split files creates at `C:\Windows\system32` and `Remove-Item` needs `$_.FullName` too. I don't what hell is going on with PS ISE, but when it started default location is selected randomly e.g. `C:\Users\a.ulianov` , `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14` and so on. One question why it won't work with files in their location?

Comment: i'm corrected script and it may be looks a little crooked, but it works.